# why there is no update in the GLKViewControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, glkview

Following an example about `GLKViewController`, I implemented update callback like the following

```
- (void)update 
{

}
```

But I checked the source, looks like there is no update message defined, why I can use update?

```
@protocol GLKViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
/*
 Required method for implementing GLKViewDelegate. This draw method variant should be used when not subclassing GLKView.
 This method will not be called if the GLKView object has been subclassed and implements -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect.
 */
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`GLKViewController` manages an animation timer that tells your app *when* to draw (and relatedly, tells you when drawing is about to happen so you can implement per-frame logic for simulations or gameplay or whatever). `GLKView` manages *how* to draw—you subclass it or use its delegate to provide rendering code.

If you subclass `GLKViewController`, you can put per-frame logic in a method whose signature is `-(void)update`. This method is not listed in the `GLKViewController` class definition because it's not a method declared or implemented by the class—it's only for subclasses. (This is described in the [`class overview documentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKViewController_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).)

Alternatively, if you use a stock `GLKViewController`, you can use your own custom class as its delegate and put per-frame logic in [`glkViewControllerUpdate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKViewControllerDelegate_ProtocolRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GLKViewControllerDelegate/glkViewControllerUpdate%3a).